# Web.config images not showing

Tags: laravel, iis, web-config

My web.config looks like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule></rules>
      </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

When I try to request an image in a sub-folder I'm getting a error:

```
HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
```

If I change the line:

```
<match url="*" />
```

to

```
<match url=".*" />
```

Then the image displays, but the rewrite for my laravel app in the root directory doesn't work and gives a 404 error.

I need to change the web.config so that both the laravel app and the images work.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
<match url="^" />
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, this has the same effect as using .* - images work, but laravel doesn't work